# How can I get started in pen-and-paper RPG as quickly as possible without any experienced players (including me)?

Tags: game-recommendation, new-players, roleplaying, new-gm

My friend and I would like to try RPGs out, but we would rather "jump to the fun" as quickly as possible and not engage any other people in the play at first. Which RPG system would be minimalistic enough to learn it within hours (the less the better) and what resources would I need to get started? I would prefer to avoid spending hours reading books just to start.

Per comments:

> What genre are you most interested in?

To be honest, I don't know what genres exist. Middle-age fantasy, magical world sounds good though.

> Do you have ready access to dice?

I've got 4-, 6-, 8- and 20-eye dice. I guess we could play online though and then I would have access to any dice using some website.

> Do you care if physical books exist for the system?

Not really, as long as it's not too much reading to play.

> What was is it about RPGs that you are most interested in?

I would say that I prefer rules rather than roleplaying — basically I enjoyed playing computer RPG games so far — creating and developing a character, staying in the same world and exploring it, making decisions.

Comment: There are a lot of rules light systems out there that can be picked up quickly. Can you provide more details to help narrow it down? What genre are you most interested in? Do you have ready access to dice? Do you care if physical books exist for the system? What was is it about RPGs that you are most interested in? Etc. I know it's difficult to try and ask a narrow question about a field you know little about, but broad questions like this get closed because no best answer is possible.

Comment: @DrewS: I answered your questions in my question. Do the answers make sense?

Comment: We get a lot of "how to start" questions that aren't fundamentally different. The answers on the other question include some of the fastest ways to get started with RPGs, so I think a need for speed doesn't fundamentally distinguish this question from it. If none of the answers solve your problem, please edit this question to indicate how it's a distinct problem that needs separate answers.